# Asprise Java OCR SDK XML format

Tags: java, xml, ocr

Is it possible to get XML scan output that provides information for each word found in the scan? For example, the current output shown in the clipping below only one set of values is provided for the entire text run "Asprise OCR and Barcode Recognition". The requirement is to get the same details per recognized word.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<asprise-ocr input="test.png">
<page no="1" width="2400" height="3200" words="122" confidence="88">
<block type="text" x="321" y="254" width="1438" height="76" words="5" confidence="86">
Asprise OCR and Barcode Recognition
</block>
...
<block type="barcode" subtype="QR-Code" x="1397" y="1484" width="441" height="441" confidence="1">www.asprise.com</block>
<block type="barcode" subtype="CODE-128" x="348" y="1489" width="583" height="145" confidence="34">Asprise</block>
</page>
</asprise-ocr>
```

Comment: I got the answer for Asprise support as `String s = ocr.recognize("C:/test.png", 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_TEXT, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_XML, "PROP_OUTPUT_SEPARATE_WORDS", true);`
(Thanks due to Jos Lee of Asprise)